# How to get Synergy to Autostart at login on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, unity, autostart, synergy

I am trying to get Synergy to autostart at boot on ubuntu 16.04 with no luck. I have seen plenty of ways to do it with 14.4 using lightdm or gnome but how does one go about it in 16.04 using Unity desktop environment.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to do it by linking the `synergy.desktop` file into your `~/.config/autostart/` folder by running the following command:

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications/synergy.desktop ~/.config/autostart/synergy.desktop
```

**EDIT:**  I know this was written a while ago, but you can also just create a link to the file to the `/etc/xdg/autostart` so that it starts before logging in. **Probably best to not have it** in both home and the xdg autostart locations at the same time so it doesn't start more than once:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/synergy.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/synergy.desktop
```

Now when you reboot your host it should auto-start synergy before the login.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it safe to copy the file? wouldn't if be better to make a link to the file?

Comment: @MikeW Sure, that would work just as good if not better.  Added an update.

Answer (score 3):

Start `Startup Applications` from the Unity dash, and **add** synergy to it. In the `command` field, enter/browse to `/usr/bin/synergy`.

Comment: The program autostarts, but I have to configure everytime I boot up. How do you make it work at the system booting up?

Comment: @Smile make sure you have the latest version, then start it manually, configure it, quit the app, and it should remember the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Add your server IP on /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with synergyc for client.

*sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf*

then paste below text:

[*SeatDefaults*]

*greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/synergyc "Server-IP/host-IP"*

then reboot